# Hashtable doesn't preserve the insertion order in Lisp

Tags: lisp

I realized that when I create an hash table in lisp, it doesn't preserve the insertion order but it's kinda random. Do you know what it could be the reason? I need it to keep the order.

Comment: I don't know anything about lisp but the point of a hash table is the hash function determines where the element goes within an array.  It never preserves order.  Why can't you use a list?

Comment: Can you please clarify _which_ "Lisp" you are talking about? Common Lisp? Scheme? Clojure? LFE?

Comment: In Java the LinkedHashMap would be such a data structure. You would need to find the Lisp equivalent in some library or define your own. Lisp usually does not provide that by default, since keeping the order of entries needs additional effort to just maintaining a hash table.

Answer (score 2):

A hash table data structure does not guarantee an ordering of its keys. This is true for Lisps as it is for other languages and language families. (*c.f.* [Drawbacks section of the Wikipedia page on Hash Tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table))

Perhaps you can restate your question to explain why you need both the (near) constant time insertion & lookup of a hash table but with an ordering constraint upon the keys. There may be another data structure that would suit your purpose better.